# Error while printing sorting array in C language?

Tags: c

I am trying make sorting function for an array. I use selection sort in an ascending order but I have no ideas what's wrong with my "output" function and I know that this similar question have been asked on stack-overflow but the answers didn't help me much. The error on Dev C++ show like "[Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void sort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int minindex;
    int t,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        minindex=i;
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
        if(arr[minindex]>arr[j])
        minindex=j;
    }
    if(minindex>1)
    {
        int t=arr[minindex];
        arr[minindex]=arr[i];
        arr[i]=t;
    }
}

void output(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%5d", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,0};
    int*a=(int*)calloc(10,sizeof(int));
    sort(a,10);
    ouput(a,10);
    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the indentation. Count the number of curly-braces `{}`. Do all the braces match?

Comment: For future reference, it's good to include the _exact_ error message and to point out the offending line in the source fragment.

Comment: you have un-matched {} in your `sort` function, which fails the compilation.  Besides that, the second line in your `main` function is pointless, you are going to sort the `arr`, so you should try `sort(arr, 10)` and then `output(arr, 10)`

Comment: `sort(a,10)` isn't this supposed to be arr

Comment: I think you need one more `}` at the end of your `sort` function, and then the `sort` function will be functionally correct, but with the wrong indentation.

Comment: Since `a` is an array of zeros, courtesy of `calloc()`, the sort operation isn't very exciting, and the output is going to be all zeros too (unless there are bugs in your sorting code).  Use `sort(arr, 10)` and `output(arr, 10)` to do something a bit more exciting.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use CodeBlocks, you can goto Plugins->Source code formatter(AStyle) to auto-format your code. Don't know about DevC++.
2. Array name is a pointer itself to the location of the first array item in memory. No need to create int* (it is unused in your code)
3. Do not define a variable until it is being used.
4. To compare two files, run a diff style program on Linux (or open files up side by side in two windows). If you are on windows, you can use meld.exe.
5. main() goes before your functions. See function declarations before main(). It is considered better. Still better would be to move functions to another file.
6. Clicking on a brace '{' should highlight the corresponding brace in any IDE.
7. Poor indentation almost always exacerbates the missing brace problem.

[image]

I am tempted to give you the code, but I am sure you can do the edits yourself.
--- Output

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : -0.000 s
Press any key to continue.
```